# NullPointerException in Iterator

Tags: java, list, loops, nullpointerexception, iterator

I have a static method where I get a list of tweets and the name of a town as a parameter and I remove from the list whichever tweet did not originate from the town or the user that made it did not originate from the town.

**Here is my code:**

```
public static void removeIncorrectTowns(List<Status> tweets, final String town) {
        if (town.isEmpty()) {
            return;
        }

        Iterator<Status> it = tweets.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Status status = it.next();
            if ((status.getPlace() == null && (status.getUser().getLocation() == null || !status.getUser().getLocation().equalsIgnoreCase(town)))
                    || !status.getPlace().getName().equalsIgnoreCase(town)) {
                it.remove();
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem I have is that I got a `NullPointerException` at line 62 which is the line with `it.remove()`.

How is it even possible for the iterator to be null? That alone makes no sense to me since the `while` loop checks if `it.hasNext()`.

Comment: First of all are you really sure this is this line? If yes, could you provide a small example demonstrating the behavior?

Comment: That is definitely the line. It says in the console line 62 and in NetBeans the line 62 is indeed the one with `it.remove()`. I am getting the tweets based on when I executed the query so replicating is a little difficult but I will try.

Comment: In your if condition, it is possible for `status.getPlace()` to be null and then later in the condition call `status.getPlace().getName()`. I am about certain this is where your NPE is occurring and I'm guessing netbeans and the console are just counting lines slightly differently.

Comment: Try a clean-build-run and see if it reports the correct line number.

Comment: @jlars62 that's exactly what I thought as well but shouldn't I be covered since -I believe- Java like C++ will calculate `status.getPlace() == null = true` then `status.getUser().getLocation() == null = true` and it will firstly ignore the second term of the first `||` since it knows the first term is `true`. Then that makes  `true && true = true` which then leaves us with `true || !status.getPlace().getName().equalsIgnoreCase(town)` which it won't calculate since the first term is already true.

Comment: Yeah but what if status.getPlace() is null and `status.getUser.getLocation()` is not null and it does not equal `town`.... I think you should double check your parenthesis.

Comment: Looks like you are right, I have messed up the structure of the `if`.

Comment: Ok, I went ahead and posted it as an answer then :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case that `status.getPlace()` is null and `status.getUser().getLocation()` is not null and does not equal `town`, you are going to get a NPE in the last part of the condition when `status.getPlace().getName()` is called.

Comment: Do you think changing my if statement to this will fix it? 

`(_status.getPlace() == null || !_status.getPlace().getName().equalsIgnoreCase(town))
                        && (_status.getUser().getLocation() == null || !_status.getUser().getLocation().equalsIgnoreCase(town))` I pretty much grouped up the `getPlace` and the `getUser.getLocation`

Comment: Yeah I think that looks better, at least for preventing NPEs. But obviously you should test it yourself with different values and make sure it always behaves correctly to know for sure.